# What is "model" in Yii2? It is array or not?

Tags: model, yii2

What is "model" in Yii2? It is array or not?  What is it?

```
 class EntryForm extends Model
{
    public $name;
    public $email;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['name', 'email'], 'required'],
            ['email', 'email'],
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Yii 2.0 model is better described [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Model is model. It's simple representation of business logic instance. In Yii2 model supports events, behaviours and properties, it's the main paradigm. And yes, model in Yii2 implements Arrayable interface and you can work with it as with array.

Comment: Alexey Pechen - Why not working array_filter($model);  if elements empty?

Comment: @Пётр you give object as argument, this is not right. You must use **toArray()** method.
Example: **array_filter($model->toArray())**

Comment: Alexey Pechen - Column 'day_birth' cannot be null   ------ not remove day_birth.  I use - array_filter($model->toArray());

Comment: @Пётр looks like message from database or model's validator. Maybe, your array_filer callback is sensitive for empty elements. This is not enough information  about your problem and this is new problem, not about Yii2 model conception.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a boss and he want you to implement a web application that has a form that the form contain some fields:

1. User email (This field must be entered),
2. User name (Must be in English only),
3. User message (Maximum 140 characters).

Let for look at boss necessary fields:

- The form must be have 3 item,
- User Email field must have a valid pattern, something like firstpart@secondpart.domain,
- User Email field is necessary and if not entered, we must refuse submitting operation,
- User Name field must only contains English (A-Z and a-z) letters,
- User Message field can be at maximum 140 characters.

This rules called **Business Rules** or in short biz-rules. Now **model is a class that implements business rules**. So type of model is class and a model is an instance of a class. This is all about model concept.

Furthermore we have another concept: **Active Record**. Simply Active Record convert a row of an table on the database to an object. For example you have a table named `user` that have 3 field: `id`, `username` and `password`, if you use an active record and select a record from `user` table with that, you have an object with three property: `id`, `username` and `password`, so for example you can use username with `echo $objectName->username;` that `$objectName` is name of our active record instance.

Now we can combine active record concept with model concept: **If we have a model class that represent a record of a table on database, we call it an Active Record Model**. Thus we can implement a class that contain both business rules and operations on database.